# Having n elements in list, how can I check if they meet a condition?

Tags: python, list

Having a list which contains n elements, how can I check if every pair of elements meets a condition?

```
example = ["aabbcc", "bca", "bc"]

for item in example:
   # check code here
```

I basically want to know if all characters of "aabbcc" are inside "bca", then "bca" is in "bc" and "aabbcc" in "bc".

Having always three elements in list is easy but how can I test all the pairs having a list which has - for example - 15 elements?

Comment: Use `itertools` to get all the combinations. Then use `all()` to test all of them against the condition.

Comment: Do you want every pair of elements -- or every pair of *adjacent* elements? The latter is a simple loop. What have you tried?

Comment: Actually, in a list of three elements I need to check if all the characters of the first element are in the second element, if all chars of the second in first, if all chars of the second in third, if all chars of third element in second, if all chars of first are in the third and if all chars of third element are in the first.

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  We expect you to make an honest attempt at the program before posting.  Stack Overflow is for *specific* coding problems; we generally don't analyze general problems for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `set.issubset` and the pairwise recipe using `itertools.tee` but `map` won’t work as it doesn’t unpack arguments but `itertools.starmap` will.

```
>>> example = ["aabbcc", "bca", "bc"]
>>> s, s1 = tee(map(set, example)); next(s1, None)
>>> list(starmap(set.issubset, zip(s, s1)))
[True, False]
>>> all(starmap(set.issubset, zip(s, s1)))
False
```